# Looping Through and Displaying Deeply Nested Objects/JSON with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an API request and running the data through groupBy and sortBy to get a slightly more structured object. Then I save it to the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTeamData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
              `https://example.com/api-call`,
            ).then((result) => {
                let teams = _.groupBy(_.sortBy(result.data.results, "season"), "player_profile.team");
                setTeamInfo(teams);
            });
          };
          fetchTeamAffinityData(); 
      }, []);
```

This gives me an object similar to:

```
{
    Angels: [
        0: {
            player_profile:{
                name: "John Doe",
                number: "10"
            },
            season: 1
        },
        1: {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Mike Trout",
                number: "21"
            },
            season: 2
        }
    ],
    Diamondbacks: [
        0: {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Randy Johnson",
                number: "51"
            },
            season: 1
        },
        1: {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Brandon Webb",
                number: "16"
            },
            season: 2
        }
    ],
}
```

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
Team: Angels
Player 1: John Doe
Player 1 Number: 10
Player 2: Mike Trout
Player 2 Number: 21

Team: Diamondbacks
Player 1: Randy Johnson
Player 1 Number: 51
Player 2: Bradon Webb
Player 2 Number: 17
```

Here is what I've tried, which gives me a loop of the team names. But since I'm mapping the object keys, I lose the actual data for the nested object.

```
{Object.keys(teamAffinityInfo?? "").map((team, index) => (
    Team: {team}
))}
```

How can I work with deeply nested objects in a sensible way?

Comment: Have you already tried with `Object.entries`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1):

Based on your approach, you could store Object.keys() and then iterate on those keys to implement your logic.

JS

```
const teams = Object.keys(object1)

teams.forEach(team => {
   const playerProfiles = Object1[team]

   playerProfiles.forEach(p => {
      // Your logic here
   })

})
```

Better approach would be to use Object.entries() as mentioned by *Ogod* in the comment.

JS

```
const object1 = {
    Angels: [
        {
            player_profile:{
                name: "John Doe",
                number: "10"
            },
            season: 1
        },
        {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Mike Trout",
                number: "21"
            },
            season: 2
        }
    ],
    Diamondbacks: [
        {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Randy Johnson",
                number: "51"
            },
            season: 1
        },
        {
            player_profile:{
                name: "Brandon Webb",
                number: "16"
            },
            season: 2
        }
    ],
}


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  const players = value
  console.log("Team", key)
  players.forEach((p,i) => {
    console.log("Player",i, ":", p.player_profile.name) 
    console.log("Player",i, "Number :", p.player_profile.number) 
  })
}
```

Note: I slightly changed the structure of object, by removing the index in the profiles array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const myData = { Angels: [ { player_profile: { name: "John Doe", number: "10" }, season: 1 }, { player_profile: { name: "Mike Trout", number: "21" }, season: 2 } ], Diamondbacks: [ { player_profile: { name: "Randy Johnson", number: "51" }, season: 1 }, { player_profile: { name: "Brandon Webb", number: "16" }, season: 2 } ], };

const extract = (data) => {
  const logic = {
    '*': ({ key }) => `Team: ${key[0]}`,
    '*[*].player_profile.name': ({ key, value }) => `Player ${key[1] + 1}: ${value}`,
    '*[*].player_profile.number': ({ key, value }) => `Player ${key[1] + 1} Number: ${value}`
  }
  return objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
    breakFn: ({ context, matchedBy, key, value }) => {
      context.push(...matchedBy.map((m) => logic[m]({ key, value })))
    },
    reverse: false
  })(data, []);
}

console.log(extract(myData).join('\n'));
/* =>
Team: Angels
Player 1: John Doe
Player 1 Number: 10
Player 2: Mike Trout
Player 2 Number: 21

Team: Diamondbacks
Player 1: Randy Johnson
Player 1 Number: 51
Player 2: Brandon Webb
Player 2 Number: 16
*/
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)